# multi authentication system in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating multi authentication system in laravel, I have created two sperate tables for each entity, everything works fine, but I am facing only one issue after register, users who are using web guard they can log in automatically and redirect to the user dashboard and it is perfect, but in case of other users who are using different guard, when they complete the registration process, they can not log in the system automatically.

so my question how can I enable the automatic login process for other user type once they complete the register step? below is the code that I am using in my project

**Route File**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified');

Route::get('/seller/dashboard', 'SellerHomeController@index')->name('seller.dashboard');
Route::get('/seller/login','Auth\Seller\SellerLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('seller.login');
Route::post('/seller/login','Auth\Seller\SellerLoginController@login');
Route::post('/seller/logout','Auth\Seller\SellerLoginController@logout')->name('seller.logout');
Route::post('/seller/password/email','Auth\Seller\SellerForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('seller.password.email');
Route::get('/seller/password/reset', 'Auth\Seller\SellerForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('seller.password.request');
Route::post('/seller/password/reset','Auth\Seller\SellerResetPasswordController@reset')->name('seller.password.update');
Route::get('/seller/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\Seller\SellerResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('seller.password.reset');
Route::get('/seller/register','Auth\Seller\SellerRegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('seller.register');
Route::post('/seller/register','Auth\Seller\SellerRegisterController@register');
```

**SellerLoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Seller;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SellerLoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/seller/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:seller')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {

        return view('auth.seller.login');
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard('seller')->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('seller');
    }
}
```

**SellerRegisterController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Seller;

use App\Seller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class SellerRegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/seller/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:seller');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.seller.register');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:sellers'],
            'business_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'business_description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'business_location' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'business_website' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $seller =  Seller::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'business_name' => $data['business_name'],
            'business_description' => $data['business_description'],
            'business_location' => $data['business_location'],
            'business_website' => $data['business_website'],
            'business_logo' => 'test_logo.jpg',
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'user_type' => $data['user_type'],
        ]);
       return $seller;
    }
}// code end here
```

Comment: You should post your auth providers configuration and middlewares as well

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'seller' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'sellers',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'sellers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Seller::class,
        ], 
],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you didn't defined the `guard` method on the `SellerRegisterController` and the default implementation retrieves the default driver (which is `web`).

That guard method provides the guard to the automatic login process in the `register` method of the `RegistersUsers`:

```php
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

You have to override the `guard` method in your `SellerRegisterController` class to return the correct driver and allow the trait to perform the login process on the correct `sellers` driver:

```php
/**
 * Get the guard to be used during registration.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('sellers');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Auth by default take User table as the main data. In case you want to do multiple auth, first thing you need to do is create a model with Notifiable trait

Model

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;
}
```

After that, you need to create the guard and provider in `config/auth.php`
The example like this

```
<?php

[...]
'guards' => [
    [...]
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'writer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'writers',
    ],
],
[...]
```

And

```
[...]
'providers' => [
    [...]
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'writers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Writer::class,
    ],
],
[...]
```

And in the login controller, you will need to check which guard is trying to login by doing this line

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))
```

If you need more detail about it, try to read this https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel

Comment: yes, I am using the same pattern as you are mentioning, but the problem is, that I am facing to redirect the writer or admin to the dashboard page, after the registration. So I want, if someone registers as a writer then very next step after registration process the writer should be logged automatically rather than to login in manually by using writer login page, I don't know why this is happening, while in the default user table, the user automatically login once they complete the registration.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Adminmiddleware
 if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1)
      {
        return $next($request);
      }else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
      }

//  Authormiddleware
 if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2 )
      {
        return $next($request);
      }else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
      }

// Admin Route
Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function (){
    Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');


});
// Auhtor Route
Route::group(['as'=>'user.','prefix'=>'user','namespace'=>'Author','middleware'=>['auth','user']], function (){
    Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

// only auht route
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']], function(){
    Route::post('favorite/{post}/add','FavoriteController@add')->name('post.favorite');
    Route::post('review/{id}/add','ReviewController@review')->name('review');
    Route::get('file-download/{id}', 'PostController@downloadproject')->name('project.download');
    Route::post('file-download/{id}', 'PostController@downloadproject');
});
```